# CSRF токены C# + Python + Django Framework

Tags: django, csrf

Реализовываю авторизацию на сайте (Python + Django) на C#. Встал вопрос о защите от CSRF атак (до этого на всех views стоял декоратор @csrf_exempt, потому что в отладке неудобно, да и не до него). Собственно, был обработчик запроса на аутентификацию вида:

```
    def AuthentificationPost(request):
        form = AuthentificationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
            if user is None:
                response = u'Не верный логин или пароль.'
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error': response, 'result': 'error'}))
            else:
                login(request, user)
                user.save()
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'success'}))
        else:
            errors = {}
            for i in form.errors:
                errors[i] = form.errors[i][0]
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'errors': errors, 'result': 'error'}))
```

Естественно, если на стороне клиента сразу начать авторизироваться, проверка на csrf пройдена не будет, т.к. клиент не получил куку с токеном, а значит нечего отправить в ответ серверу. В мануалах (официальных, и не очень) везде разжевано, как передает токен django, но ни где не сказано *когда, и при каких условиях*. Это я понял, когда проверил, что HttpResponse(status=200) не возвращает никакие куки. После чего придумал вот такое решение:

```
    def AuthentificationPost(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return HttpResponse(get_token(request))
        else:
            form = AuthentificationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']

                user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
                if user is None:
                    response = u'Не верный логин или пароль.'
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error': response, 'result': 'error'}))
                else:
                    login(request, user)
                    user.save()
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'success'}))
            else:
                errors = {}
                for i in form.errors:
                    errors[i] = form.errors[i][0]
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'errors': errors, 'result': 'error'}))
```

Проблема решена. Теперь кука приходит. Но, теперь при переходе на страницу аутентификации в браузере показывается строка с токеном, а в идеале должна быть 404. Поэтому возникает вопрос: все ли я правильно делаю? Есть более кошерное решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Истина, как в оказывается в большинстве случаев, была рядом. После тщательного штудирования англоязычных ресурсов выяснилось, что кука с токеном привязывается к сессии, поэтому нет смысла искать ее до аутентификации. Это еще и говорит и том, что шаблонный тег {% csrf_token %} в формах регистрации и аутентификации не имеет практического смысла.